# What does the following bit of code mean/do?

Tags: c

I think this is an odd way of writing something in C, but I know I've seen it before. I am unable to recall what this line does. THis is the start of a long loop, so how does it work exactly?

```
if(ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin));
```

How does this if statement work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon at the end of that statement makes the `if` statement completely useless.

After removing the semicolon, that `if` statement is extremely bad form, and should be either rewritten as

```
if ( (ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin)) != NULL )
{
}
```

or

```
ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);
if ( ret_val )
{
}
```

The reason it's bad form is that it's a common error to mistakenly use an assignment operator `=` where the equality operator `==` was intended.  The two forms shown above make it clear that the assignment was intentional, and not just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) site

> The C library function char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream) reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.

Comment: No, I understand what fgets does, I pasted the wrong line. Updated

Comment: Please read the site that I referenced which explains the return value of fgets in detail and why it can be evaluated within a conditional statement such as the one you mentioned. "ret_val" is simply a variable which represents some storage location that is being assigned to. Once the assignment is complete, the conditional evaluates the value of "ret_val".

Comment: So `ret_val` will either be NULL, in which case it exits, or any other value, in which case it loops?

Comment: If the file being read is a single line followed by EOF, then fgets would simply read that line since there is no looping. If you wrapped it in a "while" loop instead and your file was more than one line, then, yes, it would of course loop until EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to consider;

(1) the return value of fgets:

- on success, fgets returns str
- on success, if end-of-file is encountered, eof indicator is set
- on success, if end-of-file is encountered, and no character is read NULL is returned
- if a read error occures, NULL is returned

(2) with an assignment statement, the value of the left-hand side is returned.  This is standard behaviour, section 6.5.16 of the C99 standard: " An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment"

So, in the first two cases above, the assignment expression returns a pointer to the string, and the last two cases the assignment expression returns NULL.  Thus, in the first two cases the body of the if-clause is executed, and in the last two cases if body of the if-clause is not taken.

So the bottom line is that the line of code that the op posted is equivalent to these two lines:

```
ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);
if(ret_val);
```

Hope this helps.